# myScanner.hasNextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Need to use the Scanner to know if the input is an int .... but with out taking into account the ","

coordinates are in the form of x,y ; including the "," so when scanning for int need to disregard the ","

As of right now i am getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     Duplicate local variable coordinate1    Cannot invoke
>   split(String) on the primitive type int at
>   LinearSlopeFinder.main(LinearSlopeFinder.java:20)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LinearSlopeFinder {


        public static void main(String[]args){
            double x1, y1, x2, y2, n1, equation, constant = 0 ;
            double slope, slope1, slopeAns;
            int totalAmount, coordinate1;

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
             coordinate1 = myScanner.nextInt();
            } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you must use whole numbers.What is the first set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");
            String coordinate1 = myScanner.nextLine();//Int not provided
        }

        String coordinates[] = coordinate1.split(",");
        x1 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
        y1 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);

        System.out.print("    What is the second set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");
        String coordinate2 = myScanner.nextLine();
        String coordinates1[] = coordinate2.split(",");
        x2 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates1[0]);
        y2 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates1[1]);

        //remember it is Rise over Run Y's over X's
        slope = (y1-y2);
        slope1= (x1-x2);
        slopeAns= slope / slope1 ;
        if ( slope > 0 && slope1 > 0 ){
            slope = slope * -1;
            slope1 = slope1 * -1;
        }



        System.out.println("your cordinants are " + coordinate1 + " and "+ coordinate2);
        System.out.println("the slope of your line is ");
        System.out.println(slope );
        System.out.println("_____");
        System.out.println(slope1);


        if (x1 == 0){
            constant = y1;
        }
        else if (x1 != 0){
            constant = y1 - (x1*slopeAns);
        }

        if ( constant == 0){
        System.out.println("your equation for a linear line is y=" +slopeAns +"x" );
        }
        else if ( constant > 0){
            System.out.println("your equation for a linear line is y=" + slopeAns +"x+" + constant );
        }
        else if ( constant < 0 ){
            System.out.println("your equation for a linear line is y=" +slopeAns +"x" + constant );

        }
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("To check your answer you can insert your original coordinates into y=" + slopeAns + "x+" + constant );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or rename the local declaration of The  `coordinate1` variable declared within the `main()` method. It is int type.

EDIT: I've remove the static field and some changes:

```
public class LinearSlopeFinder {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        double x1, y1, x2, y2, n1, equation, constant = 0 ;
        double slope, slope1, slopeAns;
        int totalAmount;
        String coordinate1;

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");
        coordinate1 = myScanner.nextLine();

        String coordinates[] = coordinate1.split(",");
        x1 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
        y1 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);
        .....
```